# Java Guice - the method toProvider is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am following Guice documentation from here:
http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/

and I'm stuck at `toProvider` method. When I try to do this:

`bind(Shape.class).toProvider(ShapeProvider.class);`

I get this error:

`The method toProvider(Provider<? extends Shape>) in the type LinkedBindingBuilder<Shape> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<ShapeProvider>)`

My code below:

**Configuration class**

```
public class Configuration extends AbstractModule{
    @Override
    protected void configure(){
        bind(Shape.class).toProvider(ShapeProvider.class);
        bind(Triangle.class).to(IsoTriangle.class);
    }
```

**ShapeProvider class**

```
public class ShapeProvider implements Provider<Shape> {
    private int length;
    @Inject
    public ShapeProvider(int length){
        this.length = length;
    }
    public Shape get(){
        Shape triangle = new Triangle(length);
        return triangle;

    }
}
```

**Shape interface**

```
public interface Shape {

}
```

**Triangle class**

```
public class Triangle implements Shape{
    int length;
    public Triangle(){
    }
    public Triangle(int lenght){
        this.length = lenght;
    }
}
```

Do I miss something or there is something that is not mentioned in documentation?

**Update:**

**Provider interface:**

```
public interface Provider<T> {
    T get();
}
```

Comment: check your Provider import. You might be importing the wrong one

Comment: @dhamibirendra thanks for a hint, even though this was not it, but this suggested what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. I thought I needed to implement provider interface myself as showed in Google/Guice documentation, but it was showed just how that interface looks. So I accidentally overridden original Provider interface. When I deleted my Provider interface, everything solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `toProvider` you have to provide a `Provider` instance. See the javadoc of [LinkedBindingBuilder.toProvider](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#toProvider%28com.google.inject.Provider%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29)

```
bind(Shape.class).toProvider(new ShapeProvider());
```

or you should use `to` which takes a class as parameter. See also the javadoc of [LinkedBindingBuilder.to()](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/binder/LinkedBindingBuilder.html#to%28java.lang.Class%3C?%20extends%20T%3E%29)

```
bind(Shape.class).to(ShapeProvider.class);
```

**EDIT**

I can not reproduce your problem. I created a few classes to simulate the problem (because I don't want to setup guice now) but as I expeced... there is no compiler error.

The following code is type-equivalent to the guice api and it compiles.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedBindingBuilder<Shape> linkedBindingBuilder = new LinkedBindingBuilder<Shape>();
        linkedBindingBuilder.toProvider(new ShapeProvider());
    }

    public static class ShapeProvider implements Provider<Shape> {
        public Shape get() {return null;}
    }

    public static class Shape {}

    public static class LinkedBindingBuilder<T> {

        public ScopedBindingBuilder toProvider(Provider<? extends T> provider) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static interface Provider<T> {
        T get();
    }

    private static class ScopedBindingBuilder {}
}
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. Eclipse suggests me to do this -  inside `toProvider`: `(Provider<? extends Shape>)`. Then error disappears, but it seems I have to show in provider that it extends/implements Shape?.. But I showed it like Provider<Shape> is it not enough?

Comment: @Andrius I can't reproduce the problem. See the example code.